# Various Different Process Running With One Window Open - Task Manager

Tags: microsoft-edge, task-manager

I have this issue with various different applications such as Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Word that will show more processes running than windows I have open and it is boggling down my processing power. For example, I have five (5) tabs open under one window in a Microsoft Edge browser but the task manager is running 47 different instances of Microsoft Edge. I've seen the same thing happen with Microsoft Outlook, Word, Adobe, etc and I don't know how to limit them, or which ones to close or to cap it so it doesn't take up my CPU processing power. I am also curious to know if the vertical tab bar having shortcuts may play a factor in this but I don't see anything online.
Is there any explanation to this? Please see attached picture.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are *many* applications that have numerous processes, far more than the number of windows displayed. That is normal; Windows supports [multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)), which allows a browser to both fetch data over the internet and to display it as a video, for example.
2. That said, less powerful machines have difficulty supporting many simultaneous tasks. Here are a few things that might help:

   - Change an application's priority. For example, if a video is stuttering, increase priority to *Above normal*. If a background System task is hogging CPU time, set it *Below normal*. *Caution:* a task set to *Real time* may be unstoppable!

     [image: Set app pririty]
   - Shut any application you don't need.
   - Some apps vie for the same resources. For example, *Zoom* and *Edge* may contest over [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) resources. Try not to use them simultaneously.
   - Some applications allow you to set limits for the number of threads. For example, *Firefox* has settings for the maximum number of processes it will spawn. Pick the apps that work best on your PC.

     [image: Set Firefox process count limit]